# How to represent rating in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a `Ratings` table which has 3 columns: `location_id`, `rating`, `user_id` (where user_id and location_id are foreign keys in other tables). I'd like a constraint on on rating so that it can only be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

My first thought was

```
CREATE TYPE rating as ENUM('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5')
```

Is this a good way to represent ratings, or are there better or more efficient ways to store ratings please?

I'm new to SQL so apologies if I've missed something obvious but I couldn't find this question elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

enums are rarely a good choice.

If you want to restrict an integer column to a specific range, use a check constraint:

```
alter table ratings
   add constraint check_rating
   check (rating between 0 and 5);
```